# How to find the work of each force acting on a block?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, forces, work

A push of 200 N moves a 100 N block up at 30º inclined plane. The coefficient of kinetic friction is 0.25 and the length of the plane is 12 meters.

a. Find the work done by each force that acts on the block..

b. Show that the net work done by these forces is the same as the work of the resultant force.

What I've tried:
I made a freebody diagram consisting of the normal force, gravitational force, force of friction, and applied force.

I think the work of gravity is = (mg cos 30)* 12.
Other than that, I am stumped.

Comment: Welcome to Physics! Please note that this site is not a place to obtain solutions to worked problems. Please see [this Meta post on asking homework-like questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/714/25301) and [this Meta post for "check my work problems"](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6093/25301).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The work of a force that is constant (which is the case for all 4 forces acting on this block), is calculated like this:

Work = Magnitude of the force x Displacement in the direction of the force.

Work done by applied force:
The magnitude is 200N and the displacement in it's direction is 12m.
Hence
W=200*12=2400J

Work done by the normal: the displacement in the direction of the normal is 0, hence
W=0J

Work done by friction:
The magnitude is the friction coefficient times the normal.
The normal force will have a value of $50\sqrt{3}$. The magnitude of friction will be $0.25\cdot50\sqrt{3}=12.5\sqrt{3}$. The diplacement in the direction of friction will be negative 12 (-12), since they're opposite. Hence,
W=$12.5\sqrt{3}\cdot-12=-150J$

Work done by gravity:
The magnitude of gravity is 100N.
The displacement in the direction of gravity will be the height of the inclined plane, but negative, since gravity points downwards, and the block is moving upwards.
The height of the plane is 6m, so the displacement in the direction of gravity is -6.
Hence
W=100*-6=-600N

Total work=$2400+0+(-150)\sqrt{3}+(-600)=1800J-150\sqrt{3}J$

The total force in the block is the applied force, plus the component of gravity along the plane, plus friction; they are respectively, 200N, -50N and -$12.5\sqrt{3}$N. So the total force is
$F=150-12.5\sqrt{3}$ (Newtons)

The total work comes from multiplying this by 12m, which is
$W=1800J-250\sqrt{3}J$